# Socket io Angular Node datos en tiempo real se almacenan datos no necesario

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, socket

Estoy realizando un sistema de subasta en linea.
Tengo un problema al realizar una pujas desde varios usuarios al mismo tiempo y si ingreso valores iguales. Ejemplo:

```
Usuario 1 - Valor de puja 100       enviado a las 17:00:00
Usuario 2 - Valor de puja 100       enviado a las 17:00:00
```

CODIGO  DE MI BACK

```
socket.on("guardarPuja",async (objeto)=>{
    
    const pujas = await Puja.find({autorizaciones: objeto.autorizaciones})
    .populate('usuario', 'nombre apellido email imagen')

    const newPuja = new Puja(objeto);
   
   

    const ultimp = pujas[pujas.length-1]
    console.log('ULTIMA PUJ')
    console.log(ultimp.valorPuja)

    if(ultimp.valorPuja == objeto.valorPuja){
        console.log('Valores Iguales')
    }else if(objeto.valorPuja<ultimp.valorPuja){
        console.log(objeto.valorPuja)
        console.log(ultimp.valorPuja)

        console.log('Debe ser mayor')
    }else if(ultimp.valorPuja!=objeto.valorPuja && objeto.valorPuja>ultimp.valorPuja){

        console.log('Diferentes')
        const savedPuja = await newPuja.save()
        console.log(savedPuja)        
        socket.broadcast.emit("reveiceMessage", pujas)
    }
  })
})
```

Alguien talvez algun idea?

---

Y DESDE EL FRONT ENVIO LOS DATOS ALGUIEN TALVEZ QUE ME AYUDE

Comment: Necesitas transacciones. Al iniciar una transacción, bloqueas la "tabla" y al finalizar la libreras, esto evita el problema de concurrencia.